# How to view single maildir in mu4e-headers?

Tags: mu4e

Is there any variable in mu4e setup which allows to view messages from a single maildir in mu4e-headers buffer instead of multiple maildirs?

I am using mu4e and mbsync to read emails from multiple e-mail accounts, say ac1 and ac2. I followed the instructions from [the documentation](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Contexts.html) (and some other sources on the web) to set up contexts. There are multiple emails where the multiple email accounts are in Cc or Bcc (e.g. email "To" ac1 with "Cc" to ac2).

My problem is that the mu4e-headers for a specific maildir (say for ac1) shows emails from other maildirs as well (say ac2), if these maildirs contain emails in the same thread.

Comment: `j` in header view for `jump to maildir` lets you view just one maildir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the key 'W' is bound to `mu4e-headers-toggle-include-related`. Pressing this will toggle between showing all the related messages in every maildir, and showing only the messages in the current maildir.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved my problem and also led me to the relevant variable. Now I am using `(setq mu4e-headers-include-related nil)` in my setup.